# I want to know what is the function of an eMIOS and how it can be interfaced with eTPU?

Tags: nxp-microcontroller

I am working in MPC5676R microcontroller.

eMIOS is Enhances Modulator I/O System. How does it work? What are the Unified Channels in it? What do they do? What are the inputs and outputs to eMIOS? How can we interface it with eTPU?

Please answer the above questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a big question, but it's more related to the host processor than the eTPU in reality. The eMIOS is an enhanced I/O system for GPIO type operations. It allows the host processor to undertake captures, PWM generation, counts, etc using a set of pins. These pins are typically grouped and each of the groups have different capabilities. The actual functions will vary from processor to processor. The eTPU can export it's clocks, this allows for interfacing with the eMIOS, again core dependent, but it allows the host processor to undertake actions timed using the clocks generated by the eTPU.

The actual how does it work? That's more complex and we could write a book on that. In fact Freescale did, it's called the RM. The concept though is a set of GPIO pins with modular function driver in hardware that can be multiplexed into each pin. These are connected to the eTPU clocks.